# How do the lambda functions in this solution actually work?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to understand a solution to a problem that involves lambda functions, but I can't get just one part through my head.

#### Problem Statement

```
seven(times(five())) # must return 35
four(plus(nine())) # must return 13
eight(minus(three())) # must return 5
six(divided_by(two())) # must return 3
```

Requirements:

1. There must be a function for each number from 0 ("zero") to 9 ("nine")
2. There must be a function for each of the following mathematical operations: plus, minus, times, dividedBy (divided_by in Ruby and Python)
3. Each calculation consist of exactly one operation and two numbers
4. The most outer function represents the left operand, the most inner function represents the right operand
5. Division should be integer division. For example, this should return 2, not 2.666666...:

#### Solution

```
def zero(f = None): return 0 if not f else f(0)
def one(f = None): return 1 if not f else f(1)
def two(f = None): return 2 if not f else f(2)
def three(f = None): return 3 if not f else f(3)
def four(f = None): return 4 if not f else f(4)
def five(f = None): return 5 if not f else f(5)
def six(f = None): return 6 if not f else f(6)
def seven(f = None): return 7 if not f else f(7)
def eight(f = None): return 8 if not f else f(8)
def nine(f = None): return 9 if not f else f(9)

def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y
def minus(y): return lambda x: x-y
def times(y): return lambda  x: x*y
def divided_by(y): return lambda  x: x/y
```

#### My Issue

In `def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y`, how are both arguments passed to this function? I understand that it has something to do with "closure", but I'm not able to find any documentation that helps me understand it in *this* context.

For example: `three(plus(one()))` expands to `return 3 if not plus() else plus(3)`.

Then, `plus(3)` expands to `return lambda x: x + 3`. *Where does that x get its value from?*

Comment: Hint: `three(plus(one()))` doesn't expand to that. What is `plus(one())`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In `def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y`, how are both arguments passed to this function?

It doesn't -- or at least, `plus()` doesn't pass both arguments into the lambda function. `plus(3)` returns `lambda x: x + 3` -- a function that takes in one argument and increments its argument by 3. This process is known as [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

To address your example, `three(plus(one()))`:

- `one()` returns `1`.
- `plus(one())` becomes `plus(1)` and returns `lambda x: x + 1`.
- `three(plus(one())` becomes `three(lambda x: x + 1)`. `three()` calls the lambda function passed in with an argument of 3 and returns the resulting value. This gives a final result of 4.

Comment: Well that's a hell of a miss on my part. Didn't realize how those lambda functions were called. Thanks!

Comment: Don't sweat it -- wrapping your head around higher-order functions takes time and practice, and it can be very intimidating at first glance. :)